# React Native - change icon color on press

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

When the 'check' icon is being pressed, I want it to change color from default red to green. In my case, while I have another function for onpress, I use this conditional color statement

```
<Icon name="check" size={20} color={this.state.isCompleted ? '#1DA664' : '#DE5347'} onPress={() => this.isCompleted(rowData)} isCompleted={this.state.isCompleted}/>
```

I call this function for onpress

```
isCompleted(rowData){
     if (this.state.status != 'new'){
  this.itemsRef.child(rowData.id).update({
    status: 'completed'
  });
  this.setState({
    isCompleted: true
  })
}
}
```

When one of the icon in a list view is pressed, the icon changed color but everytime the color change is the icon of last item.

As shown in pic,

[image]

When I press on item 'cook lunch' , it should be the icon in cook lunch turn to green. Instead, the icon in the last item 'hello' changed. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is the component containing the icon in a separate component that has explicitly bound the isCompleted() event handler to itself? Also, assuming a parent component is using [some array].map() to render the tasks, are you assigning a unique ID to each child component?

Comment: Hi @androo, isCompleted is bound to icon element upon onpress, so i made it if isCompleted, that icon color will change. could there any way to set the color inside isCompleted function ?

Answer (score 3):

Solve this problem by creating a button component with a state and touchableOpacity.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const Boton = () => {
  const [estado, setEstado] = useState(false);

  const agregarFavoritos = () => {
    setEstado(!estado);
  };

  console.log(estado);

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => agregarFavoritos()}>
        <Ionicons
          name={estado ? 'md-heart' : 'md-heart-empty'}
          size={20}
          color="#ff6347"
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Boton;
```

Then I import the component where I want it to be displayed

```
import Boton from '../Botones/Boton';
```

Then I call the 'Boton' where I imported my component 'Boton'.

```
<Boton/>
```

Ready, the state is controlled by the component 'Boton'.

Answer (score 1):

Use `touchableHighlight`, it has `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` equivalent functions

```
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={()=>{console.log("pressed");}}
  onShowUnderlay={()=>this.setState({touchableHighlightMouseDown:true})}
  onHideUnderlay={()=>this.setState({touchableHighlightMouseDown:false})}>
    <View>
        # Your other Views here
        <Icon color={this.state.touchableHighlightMouseDown?'#333333':(this.state.isCompleted ? '#1DA664' : '#DE5347')}
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

If you just want some feedback (and not any specific color changes) during `mouseDown` activity, you can simply use one of or both of the following properties

```
activeOpacity=0.8
underlayColor={'#EEE'}
```

Comment: this is somewhat incorrect! If you set the set than all the images say if there are more than 5 images then all the images will be set to the new state and all will have a new color. This would not be to something specific.

Comment: make TouchableHighlight extend React.Component and now each piece is a component with it's own state. Now you can call <MyComponent props="myProps"> the react way.